# Looping Results with an External API Call and findOneAndUpdate

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am trying to write a program that gets the documents from a mongo database with mongoose and process them using an API and then edits each document in the database with the results of the processing. My problem is that I have problems because I don't understand completely nodejs and the asynchronous. This is my code:

```
Model.find(function (err, tweets) {
    if (err) return err;
    for (var i = 0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
        console.log(tweets[i].tweet);
        api.petition(tweets[i].tweet)
            .then(function(res) {
                TweetModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: tweets[i]._id}, {result: res}, function (err, tweetFound) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log(tweetFound);
                });
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
    }
})
```

The problem is that in the findOneAndUpdate, tweets is undefined so it can't find that id. Any solution? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core thing you are really missing is that the Mongoose API methods also use ["Promises"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), but you seem to just be copying from documentation or old examples using callbacks. The solution to this is to convert to using Promises only.

### Working with Promises

```
Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1}).then(tweets => 
  Promise.all(
    tweets.map(({ _id, tweet }) => 
      api.petition(tweet).then(result =>   
       TweetModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { result }, { new: true })
         .then( updated => { console.log(updated); return updated })
      )
    )
  )
)
.then( updatedDocs => {
  // do something with array of updated documents
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Aside from the general conversion from callbacks, the main change is using [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to resolve the ouput from the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) being processed on the results from [`.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) instead of the `for` loop. That is actually one of the biggest problems in your attempt, since the `for` cannot actually control when the async functions resolve. The other issue is "mixing callbacks", but that is what we are generally addressing here by only using Promises.

Within the [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) we return the `Promise` from the API call, chained to the [`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate) which is actually updating the document. We also use `new: true` to actually return the modified document.

[`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) allows an "array of Promise" to resolve and return an array of results. These you see as `updatedDocs`. Another advantage here is that the inner methods will fire in "parallel" and not in series. This usually means a faster resolution, though it takes a few more resources.

Note also that we use the "projection" of `{ _id: 1, tweet: 1 }` to only return those two fields from the [`Model.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find) result because those are the only ones used in the remaining calls. This saves on returning the whole document for each result there when you don't use the other values.

You could simply just return the [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) from the [`findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findoneandupdate_findOneAndUpdate), but I'm just adding in the `console.log()` so you can see the output is firing at that point.

Normal production use should do without it:

```
Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1}).then(tweets => 
  Promise.all(
    tweets.map(({ _id, tweet }) => 
      api.petition(tweet).then(result =>   
       TweetModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { result }, { new: true })
      )
    )
  )
)
.then( updatedDocs => {
  // do something with array of updated documents
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Another "tweak" could be to use the "bluebird" implementation of [`Promise.map()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html), which both combines the common [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)(s) implementation with the ability to control "concurrency" of running parallel calls:

```
const Promise = require("bluebird");

Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1}).then(tweets => 
  Promise.map(tweets, ({ _id, tweet }) => 
    api.petition(tweet).then(result =>   
      TweetModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id }, { result }, { new: true })
    ),
    { concurrency: 5 }
  )
)
.then( updatedDocs => {
  // do something with array of updated documents
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

An alternate to "parallel" would be executing in sequence. This might be considered if too many results causes too many API calls and calls to write back to the database:

```
Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1}).then(tweets => {
  let updatedDocs = [];
  return tweets.reduce((o,{ _id, tweet }) => 
    o.then(() => api.petition(tweet))
      .then(result => TweetModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { result }, { new: true })
      .then(updated => updatedDocs.push(updated))
    ,Promise.resolve()
  ).then(() => updatedDocs);
})
.then( updatedDocs => {
  // do something with array of updated documents
})
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

There we can use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to "chain" the promises together allowing them to resolve sequentially. Note the array of results is kept in scope and swapped out with the final `.then()` appended to the end of the joined chain since you need such a technique to "collect" results from Promises resolving at different points in that "chain".

---

### Async/Await

In modern environments as from NodeJS V8.x which is actually the current LTS release and has been for a while now, you actually have support for `async/await`. This allows you to more naturally write your flow

```
try {
  let tweets = await Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1});

  let updatedDocs = await Promise.all(
    tweets.map(({ _id, tweet }) => 
      api.petition(tweet).then(result =>   
        TweetModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { result }, { new: true })
      )
    )
  );

  // Do something with results
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Or even possibly process sequentially, if resources are an issue:

```
try {
  let cursor = Model.collection.find().project({ _id: 1, tweet: 1 });

  while ( await cursor.hasNext() ) {
    let { _id, tweet } = await cursor.next();
    let result = await api.petition(tweet);
    let updated = await TweetModel.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, { result },{ new: true });
    // do something with updated document
  }

} catch(e) {
  console.error(e)
}
```

Noting also that [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#findbyidandupdate_findByIdAndUpdate) can also be used as matching the `_id` is already implied so you don't need a whole query document as a first argument.

---

### BulkWrite

As a final note if you don't actually need the updated documents in response at all, then [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) is the better option and allows the writes to generally process on the server in a single request:

```
Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1}).then(tweets => 
  Promise.all(
    tweets.map(({ _id, tweet }) => api.petition(tweet).then(result => ({ _id, result }))
  )
).then( results =>
  Tweetmodel.bulkWrite(
    results.map(({ _id, result }) => 
      ({ updateOne: { filter: { _id }, update: { $set: { result } } } })
    )
  )
)
.catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Or via `async/await` syntax:

```
try {
  let tweets = await Model.find({},{ _id: 1, tweet: 1});

  let writeResult = await Tweetmodel.bulkWrite(
    (await Promise.all(
      tweets.map(({ _id, tweet }) => api.petition(tweet).then(result => ({ _id, result }))
    )).map(({ _id, result }) =>
      ({ updateOne: { filter: { _id }, update: { $set: { result } } } })
    )
  );
} catch(e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Pretty much all of the combinations shown above can be varied into this as the [`bulkWrite()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#bulkwrite_bulkWrite) method takes an "array" of instructions, so you can construct that array from the processed API calls out of every method above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I understand it now and it works! :)

Comment: I have changed the answer because I have another type of petition and I don't know how to change it to work with promises. Any idea of what should I change?

Comment: @isanma Of course I can simply point out there is [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise) which presents exactly the same Promise API as in the original question. If you still don't understand that, then Ask a new Question.